# How to get mouse position when using XamlBehaviorsWpf and MVVM (Formerly Interactivity)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Now that [XamlBehaviorsWpf](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf) [Tag missing, but I don't have the rights to add] has replaced `System.Windows.Interactivity` in Blend SDK which is deprecated I'm struggling to figure out how to use it to get Mouse position on a canvas.

`MouseX` and `MouseY` below I think is the old `Interactivity` Syntax but I can't seem to find a `XamlBehaviorsWpf` equivalent.
As such, using these properties creates a compile error.

The `Click` method is working and returns the coordinates at their default 999,999 value.

Does anyone know how I can get the current mouse position using `XamlBehaviorsWpf`?

**XAML:**

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas  Height="800" Background="Black">
                    <behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <behaviors:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="Click"/>
                        </behaviors:EventTrigger>
                        <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                            <behaviors:ChangePropertyAction MouseX="{Binding X, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                            <behaviors:ChangePropertyAction MouseY="{Binding Y, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                        </behaviors:EventTrigger>
                    </behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public void Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(X.ToString() + ","+ Y.ToString());
    }

    private double x = 999;

    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { SetAndNotify(ref this.x, value); }
    }

    private double y = 999;

    public double Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { SetAndNotify(ref this.y, value); }
    }
```

Comment: You missed a u out of mousemove.

Comment: Thanks for that, just updated the question which still stands, but I need to re-check all the things I tried to ensure the typo didn't exist all along.

Comment: ok, I've got it working now, I was going to just delete question as there's a very good article that explains how to do this. Just in-case someone stumbles on this first, I'll provide the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lot of my issues seemed to stem from a typo, which been corrected in the question (thanks Andy).
There's an easy to follow article [here](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/how-to-get-mouse-cursor-position-in-wpf-mvvm-applications/) that I used to get it working.
You can basically swap all `System.Windows.Interactivity` references with `XamlBehaviorsWpf` and it will work all the same.

My working code below for easy reference or if the link above dissapears:

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Drain.Views.Cad.CadView"
             x:Name="cad"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Drain.Views.Cad"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Drain.ViewModels.Cad"
             xmlns:cad="clr-namespace:Drain.Models.Cad"
             xmlns:s="https://github.com/canton7/Stylet"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        
        
        <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" />
        </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MainPanel">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas  Height="800" Background="Black">
                        <behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <behaviors:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="Click"/>
                            </behaviors:EventTrigger>
                        </behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <vm:MouseBehaviour MouseX="{Binding X, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                               MouseY="{Binding Y, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                        </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
    public void Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(X.ToString() + ","+ Y.ToString());
    }

    private double x = 999;

    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { SetAndNotify(ref this.x, value); }
    }

    private double y = 999;

    public double Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { SetAndNotify(ref this.y, value); }
    }
```

**MouseBehaviour Class**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;

namespace Drain.ViewModels.Cad
{
   public class MouseBehaviour : Behavior<Panel>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "MouseY", typeof(double), typeof(MouseBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "MouseX", typeof(double), typeof(MouseBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

        public double MouseY
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MouseYProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MouseYProperty, value); }
        }

        public double MouseX
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MouseXProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MouseXProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove += AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove;
        }

        private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
        {
            var pos = mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
            MouseX = pos.X;
            MouseY = pos.Y;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove;
        }
    }
}
```